# What's the correct positive answer for "Isn't it?"?

Tags: phrase-request, tag-questions

When one tells me a sentence and then asks me "isn't it?" and I want to answer that I agree with him.  Then what's the correct answer?

> **Yes**,  it is.

or

> **No**,  it is.

Because if I say "yes" to the question "Isn't it" it may be understood that I agree it is not. For example:  A: "Isn't it?" B: yes.  Meaning I don't agree,  it says I think it's indeed not true. As an English learner I found it very confusing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answer the "isn't it?" tag question, following a statement, with "yes, it is" if you agree with the statement, or "no, it isn't" if you do not agree, or possibly "I don't know" if you aren't sure.

[Tag questions](https://www.perfect-english-grammar.com/tag-questions.html)